# Angular parse Json inner array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

[image]in my code I had an angular ng-repeat displaying an json object. one of the fields inside this object is an array and when I display it using angular syntax {{item.tags}} it comes up as raw json text as expected. But whenever I tried to parse this, or replace the text it is failing to do so. almost like it is ignoring the actual html and it only sees the angular syntax. I am probably doing something wrong

But this is my code

```
<div class="col-md-2">

    <div id="top-ten-list" class="list-group" ng-controller="ToptenController as topten">
        <div  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTopTen" class="list-group-item active" onclick="accordianToggle(this)" >
            <h3 class="inline-header">Top Ten Games<span class="pull-right"><i id="links-caret" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></span></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTopTen" class="panel-collapse collapse in" >
            <span ng-repeat="item in topten.gameList | limitTo:10 | reverse" bs-popover/><button type="button" bs-popover rel="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-original-title="{{item.title}}" class="list-group-item" data-content="{{item.tags}}" >
                {{item.title}}
            </button>
        </div>  
    </div>

</div>



var app = angular.module('main',[]);

//reverse JSON order.
app.filter('reverse', function() {
    return function(items) {
        return items.slice().reverse();
    };
});

app.directive('bsPopover', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find("[rel=popover]").popover({ placement: 'bottom', html: 'true'});
    };
});



app.controller('ToptenController',function(){

    this.gameList = topten;

    this.writeout=function(item){
        console.log(item);
    };

    this.printTags = function(item){
        for ( i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        console.log(item[i]);
    };

});
```

and my code is returning the image below

Ultimately I would like it to be replaced by platformerhack

this is the json I am using as reference.

```
[{
    "title": "Super Mario Unlimited",
    "description": "text desc here ",
    "image": "image href here",
    "image2": "",
    "youtube": "http://youtu.be/O8y-CTSwMr8",
    "developer": "",
    "tags": [{
        "tag": "platformer"
    },{
        "tag": "hack"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: you can use nested ng-repeat

Comment: use ng-repeat directive to display in HTML. Your response containing list values under **tags** object.